# PHP variable not returned in array

Tags: php, arrays, string, wordpress

I am trying to place a variable inside a PHP array which will work with a Wordpress plugin.  Here is the code I have:

```
function custom_list( $lists ) {
    $fil = "Dump";
    $new_lists = array(
        'ddl-list-block' => array(
            'name'      => __( 'Download Block', 'delightful-downloads' ),
            'format'    => "
              <article class=\"ddl-list-block ddl-list-item\" id=\"ddl-%id%\">

            <div class=\"download-wrap\" style=\"background-image: url('fi');\">
              <div class=\"download-item\">
                <div class=\"download-details\">
                  <h2>%title%</h2>
                  ".$fil." /* VARIABLE SHOULD APPEAR HERE */
                  <div class=\"download-meta\">
                    <div class=\"download-meta-data\"></div>
                    <a href=\"%url%\" class=\"download-link\">Download</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
            "
        ),
        'ddl-list-plain' => array(
            'name'      => 'Flain List',
            'format'    => '<i class="fa fa-download"></i><a href="%url%" title="%title%" rel="nofollow">%title% - %date%</a>'
        )
    );

    return $new_lists;
}
add_filter( 'dedo_get_lists', 'custom_list' );
```

I have tried using `.`, `{`, single quotes and double quotes, but I can not get the word "Dump" to display where it is supposed to.  The reason I am trying to get it to show the word "Dump" is just to make sure that variables can be passed through into an array, because I am using another Wordpress plugin (Simple Fields) to manage extra fields in my post types and I want to pull out one particular aspect of the field (the URL of an uploaded image), so I will be inserting something like `$my_field['url']`.  But none of the options I am aware of have even inserted a simple string into my array.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Look alright to me! "The reason I am trying to get it to show the word "Dump" is just to make sure that variables can be passed through into an array", it should work, check this quick example http://tehplayground.com/#qHkBgDvIC. The issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this solely because it answers my problem. Not necessarily because it answers the question. I guess that's because of the plugin that I used which answers to that function.

The variable I was using called a featured image, but it could not be fed into the function.  As a solution, I used their `dedo_search_replace_wildcards` filter and created another wildcard (I think I used `%fi%` or something like that), which gave me the outcome I wanted.  Shame it didn't feed native `$` variables into it.